# Why are data attributes not passed to order/create POST Request?

Tags: angular, json-api, orocommerce

I'm working on an Angular app that uses OroCommerce & [`angular2-jsonapi`](https://github.com/ghidoz/angular2-jsonapi) to interface with the Oro frontend API.

It's worked well so far, but now I need to create an `order` object from my UI and the POST request is failing.

Here are my object models:

```js
@JsonApiModelConfig({
  type: 'orderlineitems',
})
export class OrderLineItem extends JsonApiModel {
  @Attribute()
  public id: string;
  @Attribute()
  public price: string;
  @Attribute()
  public quantity: string;
  @Attribute()
  public productName: string;
  @Attribute()
  public productSku: string;
  @Attribute()
  public productUnit: string;
  @BelongsTo()
  public product: ProductSummary;
}


@JsonApiModelConfig({
  type: 'orderaddresses',
})
export class OrderAddress extends JsonApiModel {
  @Attribute()
  public id: string;
  @Attribute()
  public city: string;
  @Attribute()
  public firstName: string;
  @Attribute()
  public lastName: string;
  @Attribute()
  public organization: string;
  @Attribute()
  public postalCode: string;
  @Attribute()
  public street: string;
  @Attribute()
  public country: string;
  @Attribute()
  public region: string;
}


@JsonApiModelConfig({
  type: 'orders',
})
export class Order extends JsonApiModel {
  @Attribute()
  public id: string;
  @Attribute()
  public totalValue: string;
  @Attribute()
  public createdAt: Date;
  @Attribute()
  public updatedAt: Date;
  @Attribute()
  public paymentStatus: { code: PaymentStatusCodes, label: string };
  @Attribute()
  public paymentMethod: { code: string, label: string }[];
  @BelongsTo()
  public billingAddress: OrderAddress; // this is missing in request Payload
  @BelongsTo()
  public shippingAddress: OrderAddress; // this is missing in request Payload
  @BelongsTo()
  public customer: object;
  @BelongsTo()
  public customerUser: CustomerUser;
  @HasMany()
  public lineItems: OrderLineItem;
}
```

And here's the code making the actual request to `datastore.createRecord()` :

```js
  public createOrder(): Observable<Order> {

    const orderAddress = new OrderAddress(this.datastore, {
      city: 'Grenoble',
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      organization: 'MyOrg',
      postalCode: '38000',
      street: '123 main street',
      country: 'FR',
      region: 'Isère',
    });

    const lineItem = new OrderLineItem(this.datastore, {
      quantity: '1',
      productUnit: 'each',
    });

    const newOrder = this.datastore.createRecord(Order, {
      owner: '1',
      customer: '34',
      customerUser: '34',
      currency: 'EUR',
      paymentStatus: {
        code: PaymentStatusCodes.pending,
        label: 'lab1'
      },
      paymentMethod: {
        code: 'payment_term_1',
        label: 'payment_term_1'
      },
      lineItems: [lineItem, lineItem],
      billingAddress: orderAddress, // addresses added here
      shippingAddress: orderAddress, // addresses added here
    });

    return newOrder.save().pipe(
      map((data) => {
        return data;
      }),
      catchError(errorResponse => {
        if (errorResponse instanceof ErrorResponse) {
          return throwError(errorResponse.errors[0]);
        }
        return throwError(this.errorService.getRelevantMessage(errorResponse));
      })
    );
  }
```

As you can see I am including the fields `billingAddress` & `shippingAddress`, but the request fails with a 400 :

```json
{
   "errors":[
      {
         "status":"400",
         "title":"not blank constraint",
         "detail":"This value should not be blank.",
         "source":{
            "pointer":"\/data\/relationships\/billingAddress\/data"
         }
      },
      {
         "status":"400",
         "title":"not blank constraint",
         "detail":"This value should not be blank.",
         "source":{
            "pointer":"\/data\/relationships\/shippingAddress\/data"
         }
      },
      {
         "status":"400",
         "title":"count constraint",
         "detail":"Please add at least one Line Item",
         "source":{
            "pointer":"\/data\/relationships\/lineItems\/data"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

When I look at the Payload section of my browser, I see that indeed neither of the addresses are added to the Payload...

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you shared it seems that neither `OrderAddress` nor `OrderLineItem` has been created at the server *before* creating `Order`.

The OroCommerce Web Services API, which you are integrating with, implements the [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/). The JSON:API specification does *not* support creating multiple resources in a single request. This is only supported if implementing the [Atomic Operations extension](https://jsonapi.org/ext/atomic/).

The Atomic Operations extension is relatively new. The OroCommerce team has come up with a custom solution to create primary resource together with related resources in a single request. It uses [client-generated IDs](https://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-creating-client-ids) together with a [Compound Document](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents) for the request payload. While this solves the need, it is *not* compliant with the JSON:API specification.

Without knowing many details about [angular2-jsonapi](https://github.com/ghidoz/angular2-jsonapi), I assume that it does *not* support this custom solution OroCommerce came up with. Instead it seems to skip resources, which have not been created yet, when serializing a record as a JSON:API [resource object](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-objects).